# error in creating include file REPORT/PROGRAM statement missing

Tags: include, abap

I do some examples and i need help with one or few errors. I create : **sourse file: Type Include , Status test , Aplication system(Local object)**.

code:

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&  Include           Z_EB_MEMBERLIST13_A_SELECTION                    *
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK member
WITH FRAME TITLE text-001.
PARAMETERS: par01 AS CHECKBOX,
            par02 AS CHECKBOX,
            par03 AS CHECKBOX,
            par04 AS CHECKBOX.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK member.
```

activation (ctrl+F3) passes but if i want check syntax (ctrl+F2) show error:

> **REPORT/PROGRAM statement missing, or program type is I(INCLUDE)**

Pls: Where is problem?

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is only a warning. If this was an executable program the lack of a "REPORT" statement would be a problem; however for include programs, as soon as I include it in any report, It will compile successfully using CTRL+F2

Answer (score 2):

Include programs can not be executed (activated) as it requires that the include is referanced in a program "REPORT" somewhere. From the code you have pasted I think you want to change the program type to "executable program" in attributes of the source program and then include a "REPORT" statement at the top of your file followed by the source filename.

ie.

```
REPORT Z_EB_MEMBERLIST13_A_SELECTION.
```

Might be worth having a look at the following link for a full overview. 
http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw2004s/helpdata/en/fc/eb2d5a358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm

Of note this section taken from above link.

Best of luck.

---

Include Programs

In contrast to all other program types, include programs do not represent stand-alone compilation units with a memory area of their own. Include programs cannot be executed. They merely serve as a library for ABAP source code. They are exclusively used to organize program texts into small editable units which can be inserted at any place in other ABAP programs using the INCLUDE statement. There is no technical relationship between include programs and processing blocks. Includes are more suitable for logical programming units, such as data declarations, or sets of similar processing blocks. The ABAP Workbench has a mechanism for automatically dividing up module pools, function groups and class pools into include programs. You create your own include programs using the ABAP Editor.

Comment: I don' t executing program. I only check syntax ctrl+F2.